# by.cssContainingText not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have a div that I would like to click that looks like so:

```
<div class="CG-Item CG-B-Left ng-binding" ng-bind="SPL.showTitleText">My New SPL</div>
```

So I call this code:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.CG-Item', 'My New SPL')).click();
```

It is returning undefined. Am I missing something? Use case looks the same as documentation.

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText

Edit: Forgot to display that there was an ng-bind attribute in the html object when i first posted. I believe that's the reason it wasn't working.

Comment: Could you try calling:  element(by.cssContainingText('div.CG-Item.CG-B-Left.ng-binding', 'My New SPL')).click();

Comment: No dice with that or ('div', 'My New SPL'). I am able to call it through the repeater @ index location, so protractor is seeing it, but I want to be able to grab any of those items via their inner text

Comment: Can you add some info about the parents/children of the div, and the exact error output you are getting? I have been unable to recreate a scenario returning undefined

Comment: Failed: No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText("div", "My New SPL")

Comment: I think by.CssContainingText only checks static text, not text instantiated with ng-bind. I got what I wanted with $$('[ng-bind=blahblah]').then(function(element){...}); and then run a check if it's the element with text i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried element.all(by.cssContainingText('div', 'My New SPL')).first().click()

Answer (score 0):

putting element.all instead of just element helped me

Answer (score 0):

element.all() - It return all the elements matching locator condition so we have to use indexing or other inbuilt methods to first get elements inorder to click it.

```
element.all(by.repeater('result in memory')).get(1).click();
element.all(by.repeater('result in memory')).first().click();
```

element() - It returns a single element matching locator condition so we can directly click it.

```
element(by.id("someID")).click();
```